# What is "to sleep late"?

Tags: sleep

What does the expression "to sleep late" mean?

Does it mean " to sleep in" or "to go to bed late at night" or both?

Comment: Did you do any research on this?

Comment: Yes, but didn't find anything conclusive. That's the reason I posted it here.

Answer (score 6):

> Does it only mean "wake up late" or "sleep in"?

Yes.

> Does it also mean "to go to bed late in the night"?

No.

Answer (score 5):

You almost have the second meaning correct, but it's missing a word:

- **to sleep late**
  to sleep in or wake up late
- **to *go* to sleep late**
  to go to bed late at night

---

*[Sleep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleep)* is a simple verb:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 1 : to rest in a state of sleep

But [***go to sleep***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20sleep) is an idiom with a specific meaning:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : to begin sleeping
>    // She lay down on the couch and *went* (right) *to sleep*.
>    // Tell the kids it's time to *go to sleep*.
>    // After the party, I just wanted to *go to sleep*.

Note the use of *begin* in the definition rather than just the state itself.

It's the use of *go* that makes the specific difference in terms of the meaning.

Answer (score 4):

According to The Free Dictionary:

> **[sleep late](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+late)**: to sleep later than usual or customary; to sleep in; and

> **[sleep in](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+in)**: to oversleep (e.g., *I missed the morning train because I slept in.*) or to sleep late on purpose (e.g., *After this week's work, I will sleep in on Saturday.*)

Neither of these has anything to do with "going to bed late at night."

Answer (score 4):

It depends what variety of English you use. An ex-girlfriend of mine (from Malaysia) used it to mean "Go to bed late". I used it to mean "Oversleep."

This caused confusion between us for a while.

Comment: I also use it to mean "go to bed late", and in fact it sounds wrong to me to use it to mean "sleep in", so I was very surprised by the other answers! But upon searching the internet it seems this usage is nonstandard.

Comment: I was looking for some authentic info...